# Div is not overlapping the Parent div with overflow hidden even with z-index

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a situation where i want the menu list option to be opened outside the bordered div. I have used z-index but that is not working at all. Please help me. [This is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64xDq.png)

Html :

```
<div class="myprogram_list" #myprogram_list>
<div *ngFor='let myProgram of myPrograms;let i = index; trackBy:trackElement' class="col-md-3 programLists square-box-{{myProgram.rowIndex}}">
  <div class="programInfo">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="myProgram[i] = !myProgram[i]"><b>{{i}}</b></a>
    <span class="">{{myProgram.programName}}</span>
    <span class="">{{myProgram.leadPartner}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" [ngClass]="myProgram[i] ? 'open' : 'close'">
    <ul class="quickMenuOptions nopadding dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/quicklaunch"><i class='quickLaunch'></i>&nbsp; Quick launch</a></li>
      <li><a href="/program"><i class='managerMenber'></i>&nbsp;Manage member(s)</a></li>
      <li><a href="/program"><i class='managerExpert'></i>&nbsp;Manage expert(s)</a></li>
      <li><a href="/program"><i class="archiveProgram"></i>&nbsp;Archive program</a></li>
      <li><a href="/program"><i class="deleteProgram"></i>&nbsp;Delete program</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment due to missing reputation, but did you already try to set the css position of "dropdown" to something like `absolute` and then trying to set the z-index? And myprogram_list shouldn't have `overflow:hidden`. In that case you would have to move the dropdown OUT but NEXT to the myprogram_list element so both are on the same "layer"... O.c. you would have to write some logic to position the menu on the bottom of each selectables. But since you're dealing with Angular that should be the least of the problem :)